# git svn error happens on dcommit, but not on fetch or rebase

Tags: svn, git-svn

I am receiving the following error when I run 'git svn dcommit' on a branch of the repository:

```
HTTP Path Not Found: PROPFIND request failed on '/svn/Project/branches/3.34': '/svn/Project/branches/3.34' path not found at C:\Program Files (x86)\Git/libexec/git-core\git-svn line 4970
```

However, 'git svn fetch' and 'git svn rebase' work fine. And the main trunk dcommits just fine as well. Any suggestions?

Oh, worthy to note, the svn actual path should be /svn/Project/branches/v3.34, not just 3.34. But as noted above the other commands I regularly use still work fine with the part that breaks dcommit.

Comment: Every commit in git-svn repository should have "git-svn-id:" signature. Is it correct?

Comment: No, the id points to a path using 3.34 instead of v3.34

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution might not work depending on how many commits you have pending for dcommit, but since I had one, I deleted the local branch and re-created the local branch using the v3.34 name instead of 3.34, and dcommit magically started working.